# How to install rfc5766-turn-server as a Windows service?

Tags: windows-services, rfc5766turnserver

I've installed and configured [rfc5766-turn-server](https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/) under Cygwin. Now, how do I register it as a Windows service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a cygwin shell, run:

`cygrunsrv -I turnserver -p /usr/local/bin/turnserver -a "arguments"`

Run `/usr/local/bin/turnserver -?` to list possible `arguments`.

**WARNING**: `turnserver` assumes you are using a static ip address.
If the computer is configured to use DHCP, and the DHCP server assigns the computer a static ip, make sure the service startup type is `Automatic (Delayed Start)`. Otherwise, the server will attempt to bind to the network interface before the computer acquires an address from DHCP and fail.

If you see `Trying to bind fd <number> to <ip-address:port>: errno=125` in the log file, this is what happened.

Comment: How do you setup TLS via command line? can you please show one example? e.g: /usr/local/bin/turnserver ???andthen????

Comment: @YumYumYum Please file a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24775307/285594 - please help me on this, how should i setup the TLS? i have tried two new records call: pkey=fileto.key and cert=fileto.cert. after restarting the TURN server no error but not sure if this is what i needed for to enable TLS?