# rfc5766-turn-server - how to enable TLS and HTTP CONNECT method with it?

Tags: ssl, centos, webrtc, turn, rfc5766turnserver

I have this following setup for rfc5766-turn-server but i am not sure yet how to enable the TLS in turnserver.conf?

Any idea what is missing to make sure TLS is activated and what else related sources are missing?

```
# cat turnserver.conf
user=root:root
realm=x.x.x.x
#no-tls
#no-dtls
syslog
aux-server=x.x.x.x:80
aux-server=x.x.x.x:443
```

Problem: When TURN client connects with following primitives, to that above TURN server then there is auto TURN session close issue.

```
config: '{"iceServers":[{"urls":"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},        
         {"credential":"root","urls":"turn:root@XXXXX:443?transport=tcp"}], 
          "iceTransports":"relay"}';
```

NOTE: 443 TCP

or

```
config: '{"iceServers":[{"urls":"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},        
         {"credential":"root","urls":"turn:root@XXXXX:80?transport=tcp"}], 
          "iceTransports":"relay"}';
```

NOTE: 80 TCP

Comment: In my experience, the quickest way to get a response is to ask on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/turn-server-project-rfc5766-turn-server. Please do that and summarize the answer you receive below so other users can benefit from it.

Answer (score 5):

I guess I am answering the question bit late, hoping it would help the people who will stumble upon this question later on.

I do not think you can add users in the TURN config files directly, either a seperate flatfile/ some db or part of command for starting `turnserver` ( or through `turnadmin`)

let assume listening ip is `XXXXX` and port `PPP`( from what I understand, this port can be whatever you want, irrespective of the transport being `udp` or `tcp` and the if you are running on port <1024 you are gonna need elevated access)

using turnconfig file(turnconfig.conf):

```
listening-ip=XXXXX
tls-listening-port=PPP
cert=( certificate location)
pkey=( private key location)
lt-cred-mech
realm=someRealm
log-file=/var/tmp/turn.log
no-sslv2
no-sslv3
```

the start cmdwould be: `turnserver -v -c turnconfig.conf -o -u user:root`

without configuration file:

```
turnserver --tls-listening-port PPP -L XXXXX -r someRealm -a -o -v -n -u user:root -l '/var/tmp/turn.log' --no-sslv2 --no-sslv3
```

**Note:** is this is hosted behind NAT( usually in the case of Amazon EC2), another feild `external-ip` is required.

and config( of RTCPeerConnection on WebRTC app) is :

```
config: {
            'iceServers':[
                {
                    'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' 
                },
                {   
                    'url': 'turn:user@XXXXX:PPP?transport=udp',
                    'credential': 'root'
                },
                {   
                    'url': 'turn:user@XXXXX:PPP?transport=tcp',
                    'credential': 'root'
                }
            ]
    };
```

as for generating the certificate and private key, you can use `openssl`:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 3001 -nodes
```